# Print at a known scale in QGIS

Tags: qgis, printing, scale

Does anyone know if it's possible to layout a QGIS project for printing at a known scale?

Say 1:5000 in A0.

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is the [Print Composer](http://docs.qgis.org/2.0/en/docs/user_manual/print_composer/print_composer.html).

There is a lot of stuff that goes into the print composer, so it would probably be good to just browse the documentation, but I will try to narrow it down to just what you need.

1. Open the print composer (Ctrl+P) or Project -> New Print Composer
2. Set your composition settings in the Composition tab on the right hand side. There should be a section for changing the page size with presets (one of the presets is A0)
3. Add a map to your print composer by selecting in the top menu Layout -> Add Map. Click and drag to create your map on the page. It should snap to the edges of the page if you want the print to be full page edge to edge or you can do something smaller with some margin.
4. Set your scale and or extents of the map. On the right hand side there should be a Item properties tab. Under that you will see where you can set the scale of your map and or set X Y min max extents.
5. Once you are happy with your layout select print (ctrl+p) or Composer -> Print...